# VBA TreeView Node DoubleClick Workaround

Tags: vba, excel, treeview, double-click

I have a TreeView within a UserForm in Excel.
I'm trying to workaround an event handler for double-click in a node since the nodes in tree views only have single click event. The double click in a node will add the double clicked node to a listbox.
My idea is to check the second click by using the single click event and timers associated with public variables.

I'm finding an issue with this workaround. It's not delivering the desired results for a double click... only for a triple click!

Can anyone please give me some tips about how to solve this issue?
The double click event for a node is important for what I'm trying to achieve.

Code:

Public/Module Constants/Variables

```
Const sDblClickTime As Double = 1 'DblClick time
Dim d1ClickTime As Double '1st click timer
Dim d2ClickTime As Double '2nd click timer
Dim sClickNode As String '1st click node text
```

Single Click Node Event

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeClick(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)

If Node.Text = sClickNode Then
    d2ClickTime = Timer
    If (d2ClickTime - d1ClickTime) <= sDblClickTime Then
        frm.ListBox1.AddItem (Node.Text)
        sClickNode = ""
    Else
        d1ClickTime = Timer
    End If
Else
    sClickNode = Node.Text
    d1ClickTime = Timer
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: IIRC the treeview itself has a handler for double-click. If that's the case then you could handle the treeview's double-click and work out the selected node.